# Read a text line and save to global variable

Tags: android

```
public String serverip;
```

**serverip** is a global String variable
I want my Socket app read IP from a text file which is saved in **Server.txt** file. I have used this:

```
try {
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("mnt/sdcard/Server.txt");
    if (instream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        serverip = buffreader.readLine();
        instream.close();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

It reads the IP from file well but it does not save the IP to the **serverip** variable. if I use a static string like `"192.168.1.100"` it works fine but when reading a line from the text file it doesn't save the line to **serverip**

Comment: are you sure you read the file? I mean, you hide the code in a null check, so are you sure that `if` content is executed?

Comment: yes i am sure that it goes inside the if check by showing the serverip value in a toast

Comment: So it has the serverip value in a toast, but not afterwards?

Comment: I might be useful if you add your toast code and say what it displays.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverip,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Where did you added this toast? below serverip line or somewhere else?

Comment: just below the catch. it shows the new serverip correct but it uses the old serverip which i manually assigned with a constant string like "192.168.1.100"

Answer (score 0):

first Make sure you add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

if still not work try this:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"Server.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}

serverip = text;
```

Comment: Put that toast in your code please. Statement serverip=text; will not compile. A StringBuilder cannot be assigned to a String.

Comment: yes, that's right, this is a stingbuilder. the Toast shows the ip from text file well but when using in app it does not use it and use the old ip which i assign manually like "192.168.1.100"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the string which is read from text file is like " 192.168.1.100". note the empty character at first position. although the text file does not have a space or any other characters at the begining of the string, it still saves the result with a null value at first position, so i used subString(1) and passed it to Socket(ip,port).